# How to get connections in Mongo through driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, perl

The system I work on uses the connection table (`inprog` array) in Mongo to monitor and control system availability and concurrency. This is achieved with the wonderful `$cmd.sys.inprog` collection.

One can get a nice list of connected clients from the `mongo` client:

```
db.getCollection('$cmd.sys.inprog').findOne({ $all: 1 }).inprog
```

Using the Perl driver, the only way I was able to run that command was with:

```
$db->eval( q{ db.getCollection('$cmd.sys.inprog').findOne({ $all: 1 }) } )->{ inprog };
```

But now `eval` has been deprecated and is generating a load of deprecation warnings in our Mongo log.

The following alternative method does not work from the Perl driver:

```
$db->get_collection('$cmd.sys.inprod')->find_one({ '$all': 1 })->{inprog};
# fails with "Invalid collection name"
```

Neither from the Node Mongo driver, so it's not just the Perl driver:

```
db.collection('$cmd.sys.inprog').findOne({$all:1});
# fails with invalid connection name just the same
```

Also, I couldn't find a `$db->run_command(...)` that would do this.

Are there any alternatives to `eval` to get the `inprog` list that will work from the Mongo drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to do this with `db.runCommand()`.

```
$client->get_database('admin')->run_command([ 'currentOp' => 1, '$all' => 1 ])->{inprog};
```

Basically, the `currentOp` command will receive the command option `$all: 1` and that will resolve the call just the same as the previous collection.

It also works in Node:

```
const db = await mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/admin');
db.command({ "currentOp": true, $all: 1 });
```

Answer (score 4):

That collection name isn't a real collection; it's a pseudo-command and was removed in the 3.6 server per [SERVER-30181](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30181).  You can use the [currentOp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/currentOp/index.html) command instead.

Note that currentOp is eventually going away in favor of the [$currentOp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/currentOp/index.html) aggregation stage.  This works in the shell using `db.aggregate` but drivers don't currently support database-level (vs collection-level) aggregation pipelines.  (That feature is currently on the roadmap for the 4.2-era drivers.)